# scrollview with long image not showing

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have an imageview nested inside a scrollview. When I inserted an image about 2990px in height the image would not show, but when I cropped it to 1500px. It shows. Does anybody knows why? Does scrollview have a maximum height limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried putting the image into xxhdpi. Then it appears, but the image becomes small, and wont fit the whole parent width. So I just cut the image into two pieces. The whole image is shown now.

Comment: Hm. This is a workaround, not suitable for all needs. Does nobody have an idea, how to show larger (vertical, longer) images in a ScrollView? I have exact the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The height of scroll view will not be fixed. It increases periodically. 
It is recommended not to fix the height and width of ScrollView and leave it as a wrap content.

Comment: both scrollview and imageview's height/width is set to wrap content. The problem.  Original image is 2990px in height. Image not shown. I cut/crop the image to 1500px using image editor. Image appears.